# Decreased performance with hibernate 5.1.2 version

Tags: hibernate, jpa, seedstack

All the queries in my application is taking more time after updating hibernate version from 4.1.5 to 5.1.2, every other configuration is same.
Is there a specific compatibility between seedstack and hibernate versions?

Comment: How did you measure the performance decrease?

Comment: Are you talking about startup time or database operations performance ?